# Fixing error duplicate symbol _response in: ....: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, clang

I tried renaming my project and Xcode crashed and wouldn't open again so I created a new project and copied the files I needed in and built the project to be presented with this error...I have no clue how to fix this..Kind of desperate here..really need help

```
duplicate symbol _response in:
/Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Garda_Station_Locator-dhfsoolpnjuqneegoeyzxismsykb/Build/Intermediates/Garda Station Locator.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Garda Station Locator.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Service.o
/Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Garda_Station_Locator-dhfsoolpnjuqneegoeyzxismsykb/Build/Intermediates/Garda Station Locator.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Garda Station Locator.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/County.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Service and County files both seem to have a response symbol. Maybe the old project had a preprocessor symbol that excluded one, or maybe both files weren't actually compiled in the target.

Comment: This is the correct answer, I was thrown off by the fact they built without a problem within the previous project. Great to learn something new for the future